# Replace flyway4 tag with flyway

Tags: support, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request

All questions tagged with [flyway4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flyway4) are already tagged with [flyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flyway). This tag is redundant and should be removed.

Comment: Not all questions - I can see two on the first page of questions that are just tagged flyway4 - I don't know anything about the tech - is there a version 4 - is it different than what flyway is representing... Can you provide more info? Would someone tagging flyway4 expect a different answer than just using flyway for instance (does it change the valid answers that could be given?)

Comment: I am the author of Flyway. There is about one major version a year and older versions are unmaintained. It makes no sense to introduce a new tag each year. The existing questions can safely be retagged with flyway.

Comment: Okay done. Just to note there were 10 questions that were tagged flyway4 *only* which are now tagged flyway, and there were 66 questions tagged with both and flyway4 is now removed.

Comment: Thanks. This clears up confusion for people wanting to ask a question. Truly appreciated.